# Issues when importing project

Tags: android

Whenever I want to import/open project in android studio the name of the files/folders in my native language (Hebrew) is just squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Android Studio UI Font in

`File` > `Settings` (Ctrl+Shift+S) > `IDE Settings` > `Appearance` > `Override default fonts`

Set it to "Tahoma" which supports Hebrew.

Original answer found here: [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78968)